# ThinkPad wifi hangs at random intervals after undocking

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, thinkpad

When I undock my ThinkPad W520, the wifi connection will continue to work for a while, usually 10 or 20 minutes, but then it starts to act weird. The computer never loses its connection to the network. Web requests start to time out, and the browser just sits and spins. After a few minutes the web connection will start working again for a few minutes, then it acts up again.

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit and have the latest drivers and Windows updates installed. I've also tried some tricks like ipconfig /renew and the Windows network troubleshooter, but that doesn't help. I also wrote a PowerShell script that resets my wireless adapter, which has no effect. Same with disabling/reenabling the wifi card.

Restarting the PC, naturally, fixes the issue until I dock/undock again.

When the laptop is docked, it's connected via an ethernet cable, so I'm wondering if it's somehow having an issue cutting over to wifi.

Any suggestions for fixes or workarounds would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm experiencing the same issue. I have Lenovo Access Connections installed. I can "recover" wifi by switching to a different named access point (I have a couple where I work). So at least I don't have to reboot. My symptoms are the same - old connections continue to work, but new connections fail. I was on a skype call when it happened today, and the skype did die, which slightly goes against the theory that existing connections all continue to work.

Comment: No luck. I can confirm the issues with getting wifi working on new networks. During a recent business trip to Florida, I struggled every time I tried to connect to an access point in the airport, in my room and in conference rooms. Rebooting usually resolves the issue, but not always.